# Python : PortAudio + Opus encoding/decoding

Tags: python, portaudio, pyaudio, opus

I'm capturing audio from my mic with Pyaudio and trying to encode/decode it with the opus codec. I'm using the bindings to libopus made by SvartalF ( https://github.com/svartalf/python-opus ).

Here is my code :

```
import pyaudio
from opus import encoder, decoder

def streaming(p):
    chunk = 960
    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    CHANNELS = 1
    RATE = 48000
    streamin = p.open(format = FORMAT,
            channels = CHANNELS, 
            rate = RATE, 
            input = True,
            input_device_index = 7,
            frames_per_buffer = chunk)
    streamout = p.open(format = FORMAT,
            channels = CHANNELS, 
            rate = 48000, 
            output = True,
            output_device_index = p.get_default_input_device_info()["index"],
            frames_per_buffer = chunk)
    enc = encoder.Encoder(RATE,CHANNELS,'voip')
    dec = decoder.Decoder(RATE,CHANNELS)
    data = []
    for i in xrange(100):
        data.append(streamin.read(chunk*2))
    streamout.write(''.join(data))
    encdata = []
    for x in data:
        encdata.append(enc.encode(x,chunk))
    print "DATA LENGTH :", len(''.join(data))
    print "ENCDATA LENGTH :", len(''.join(encdata))
    decdata = ''
    for x in encdata:
        decdata += dec.decode(x,chunk)
    print "DECDATA LENGTH :", len(decdata)
    streamout.write(decdata)
    streamin.close()
    streamout.close()


p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
streaming(p)
p.terminate()
```

I must put `chunk*2` instead of `chunk` in `data.append(streamin.read(chunk*2))` or `DECDATA LENGTH == DATA LENGTH*2` and I don't know why.

Outputs :

```
DATA LENGTH :    384000  
ENCDATA LENGTH : 12865  
DECDATA LENGTH : 384000
```

Without encoding/decoding, the first `streamout.write(''.join(data))` works perfectly. With encoding/decoding, the `streamout.write(decdata)` kinda works but has a lot of cracklings mixed in.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi there! I have no time right now for python-opus support, but you can fork it and contribute, so I can update PyPI repo with a fixed version.

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be caused by a bug in python-opus in the decode methods.

According to the [Opus API](https://mf4.xiph.org/jenkins/view/opus/job/opus/ws/doc/html/group__opus__decoder.html#ga7d1111f64c36027ddcb81799df9b3fc9), **opus_decode** returns the number of samples decoded. The python bindings assume it will completely fill the result buffer it passes in so there is a silence appended to each set of decoded samples.  This silence causes the cracking at low frame sizes and a stutter at higher frame sizes.  While the documentation doesn't say anything about it, it appears that the returned number is per channel.

Changing line [150 of opus/api/decoder.py](https://github.com/svartalf/python-opus/blob/master/opus/api/decoder.py#L150) to the following fixes it for me:

```
    return array.array('h', pcm[:result*channels]).tostring()
```

The **decode_float** method probably needs the same change if you need to use that.

Answer (score -3):

Just cut output in a half and take first part.
By trial and error I have found this solution satisfying.

```
from opus import decoder as opus_decoder
from opus import encoder as opus_encoder

class OpusCodec():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.chunk = 960
        self.channels = 1
        self.rate = 48000
        self.encoder = opus_encoder.Encoder(
            self.rate, 
            self.channels,
            opus_encoder.APPLICATION_TYPES_MAP['voip']
        )
        self.decoder = opus_decoder.Decoder(
            self.rate, 
            self.channels, 
        )

    def encode(self, data, **kwargs):
        if not 'frame_size' in kwargs:
            kwargs['frame_size'] = self.chunk
        out = self.encoder.encode(data, frame_size=self.chunk)
        return out

    def decode(self, data, **kwargs):
        if not 'frame_size' in kwargs:
            kwargs['frame_size'] = self.chunk
        out = self.decoder.decode(data, **kwargs)
        return out[0:int(len(out)/2)] # hackety hack :D
```

Comment: So your going to cut the output in half? Doubt that's a good idea.